# Determining Molecule Based on Proton NMR (HNMR)

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

[image]

Based on the NMR data, I have determined that the molecule must be 1-phenoxy-2-propanone, however I may be wrong because given the proton NMR, there are only 4 unique carbon environments, however in 1-phenoxy-2-propanone, there are 5 carbon environments. In addition to that, on carbon environment "B" there is only one proton, which isn't indicated on the NMR, which makes me doubt my choice in molecules. I've basically tried every molecule and this was the closest I could get!Could anyone please correct me?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: All those edits an no one put the missing space in...

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment seems reasonable. One thing to keep in mind is that even though  phenyl protons are in different chemical environments, they may be too close to resolve and with a low-field instrument, some may appear as a "blob" of superimposed signals. In this case, the peak from (B) is simply unresolved from that of the (C) protons, giving a single signal that integrates to 3 protons. See [here](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/img_disp.cgi?disptype=disp3&imgdir=hsp&fname=HSP03910&sdbsno=13602) with a 90 MHz instrument. That spectrum is a bit different than the one you have, but the one you've been given may be a simulated spectrum.